# Python function stops working after moving it to another file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python code that works how I expect it to, and I want to move the functions `send_cmd()` to another `commands.py` file.

```
import add_pinout
from lib import *

pinout = {}

avr_board = AVRClient('COM3', 250000)

i2c_master = I2CMaster(avr_board)
i2c_slave_adress = 0x1E
i2c_device = I2CDevice(avr_board, i2c_slave_adress)


def send_cmd(cmd):
    try:
        if cmd[0][:4] == 'LCL_':
            if cmd[0] == 'LCL_ALL':
                for pin in pinout:
                    gpio_pin = GPIO(avr_board, pinout[pin], GPIO.Mode.OUTPUT)
                    if cmd[1] is '1': gpio_pin.write(True)
                    elif cmd[1] is '0': gpio_pin.write(False)
            else:
                gpio_pin = GPIO(avr_board, pinout[cmd[1]], GPIO.Mode.OUTPUT)
                if cmd[1] is '1': gpio_pin.write(True)
                elif cmd[1] is '0': gpio_pin.write(False)

        elif cmd[0] == 'WRITE':
            i2c_device.data_transfer(cmd[1], len(cmd[1]))

        elif cmd[0] == 'READ':
            print i2c_device.data_transfer([], len('1010')) 

        elif cmd[0] == 'WRITE+READ':
            print i2c_device.data_transfer(cmd[1], len('1010')) 

        else:
            print 'Something went wrong...'

    except KeyError:
        print 'Such pin does not exist.'
    except IndexError:
        print 'Not enough arguments.'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pinout.update(add_pinout.read_pins())
    print(pinout)
    while(True):
        send_cmd(raw_input().split())
```

I do it by adding `from commands.py import send_cmd` and addiing arguments  to the function. The call looks like this: `send_cmd(avr_board, pinout, i2c_device, raw_input().split())`, while the declaration in `commands.py` is `def send_cmd(avr_board, pinout, i2c_device, cmd):`. When i run the code it accepts user input, but when it calls `start_cmd` from `commands.py`, it just goes to the `else` clause, like it couldnt see the list made by `raw_input().split()`.

### Edit

I have found the error - in `commands.py` I have changed `==` into `is` in each `if` statement. I have reversed this change and now everything's fine.

Comment: After 'try' in 'def send_cmd', try printing cmd. You come know why it is going in else directly.

Comment: I have tried it, and it prints `['LCL_3V3', '1']`, when I type in `LCL_3V3 1`, so as expected...

Comment: See here for `is` vs `==` : https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/248/comparisons/1710/comparison-by-is-vs#t=201609021241423401946